# How do I escape this \ character in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to use this following in jQuery

```
:contains("C:\ My Name")
```

How do I escape the escape character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a double `\\` to get a single, like this:

```
:contains("C:\\ My Name")
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/B9yRw/).  You can find other tips like this at the top of the [selectors portion of the API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks Nick. One more thing, what about the spaces. It doesn't work without escape characters.

Comment: @Rajasankar - Are you using quotes? for example: `$('span:contains("C:\\ My Name")')`

Answer (score 3):

Use a double backslash. Also, you probably want to remove the leading space from " My Name" as that is not a valid path.

```
:contains("C:\\My Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a back-slash to escape itself. `\\`

`:contains("C:\\My Name")`